# how do I change link color in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, colors, hyperlink

I am using free Wordpress online. I want to change the color of a link. When I test this code in http://www.w3schools.com, it works well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table style="background-color:white;width:100%;">
<tbody>
<tr valign="TOP">
<td> <img border="0" src="http://www.kuffelcreek.com/favori14.jpg" width="430" height="480" /></td>
<td>
<p><div style="color: #FF0000"><a  href="google" style="text-decoration:none;" onmouseover="this.style.color='#FF0000'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#000000'">google link</a></div></p>
description
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I pasted this code in Wordpress then updated it, it automatically deleted `onmouseover="this.style.color='#FF0000'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#000000'"` and the code turned out to be like this:

```
<table style="background-color:white;width:100%;">
<tbody>
<tr valign="TOP">
<td> <img border="0" src="http://www.kuffelcreek.com/favori14.jpg" width="430" height="480" /></td>
<td>
<p><div style="color:#FF0000;"><a href="google" style="text-decoration:none;">google link</a></div></p>
description
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can I avoid Wordpress deleting my code? How can I change color of link in Wordpress?

Comment: Do you have a site hosted by Wordpress.com?

Comment: Why don't you use css rules :hover within <style></style> tags?

Answer (score 2):

To change the color of all the links using CSS, you could save this to your Appearance → Custom Design → CSS editor:

a:link, a:visited { color: #f00; }

Comment: the problem is to use that I have to buy the custom design